# magento 2 invoice pdf

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Login to customer account
2. Go to my orders > choose any order > view order
3. Go to Invoices tab or click print order

#### Expected result

Print One page similar to the invoice on the backend http://screencast.com/t/dl3VmJbN2N

### Actual result

Two page layout that looks horrible and is wasteful if printed. http://screencast.com/t/Mv0951bzD7Z
Can this be changed somehow? How?
Are there any extensions that anyone can recommend that will change this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: how is this not programming related? there is code that is needed to change this pdf layout.
there are two pdf layouts that are in magento 2 ce and they have php and xml data to change the content.

Comment: I submitted on magento.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about any code. It's like asking how to change the colour of text in a Word document and claiming that it's a programming question because Word is written in C++. The question needs to be specifically about programming.